# iOS how to launch another app as a redirection

Tags: ios, appcelerator

An app is currently outdated and to avoid the users to use its incorrect results, we decided to suspend this app until we have the algorithm updated.

We have tried the following:

```
Titanium.Platform.openURL("http://example.net");
```

This will open the web browser to a URL of our selection. However, in iOS there is a little "go back" link in the top left hand corner, which will lead the user back to the broken app. We want to avoid this. Basically, we want the app to be inactive all the time - whenever the user attempt to activate it, the designated page behind the URL should be shown.

How can we do this?

Comment: This is the default iOS behaviour and is not disablable

Answer (score 0):

Why not just temporarily replace the main page of you app with a full screen web view showing the desired URL?  The user stays in your app but still can only access the web page you direct them to.